# Sending data from Ruby(rails) code to javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently started working on a project which involves ruby on rails/javascript/jquery. I am very new to all this. The part I am involved is like this. User clicks on a button. A dialog will open, where user will enter a term to search. With that term, I am will be constructing an URI by looking at an xml. Then I will do a REST call. The response will be a XML file. I will be parsing it and displaying data in the same dialog where user entered term to search.

I am using JQuery to create a dialog. And I am doing parsing and REST call part in ruby code (Helper class). I am not using models and controller for my part. Now I need to send data from helper method to erb file where I will be displaying data as a table. Output will be like this

string11 string12 string13
string21 string22 string23
string31 string32 string33
   .        .         .
   .        .         .

For now, in ruby code I have create 3 arrays for every column. I am not sure on how to send data from ruby to html/javascript. If there is better way to do this then let me know. For ex: instead of sending as 3 separate array, is it better to send as xml/json? Or any other suggestions will be really helpful. Mainly I am not understanding on how to send this data to the erb file. Thank you in advance.

Edit: Adding a sample code

Javascript/Jquery -

On button click, I want to call a ruby method in erb file
Ex: <%= getUserList%>
erb file is also having other javascript/html code to display other stuffs.

And in helper method I have getUserList method

```
def getUserList(search)
uri = create_url(search)
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(uri))
//Doing parsing and other stuffs here
//creating 3 array as mentioned above which needs to be displayed
end
```

I want above arrays to be displayed. I am not sure on how to send these arrays to the erb file which invoked this method

Comment: Do you have some sample code of what you've tried so far?  I'm a little confused on what you're trying to do.  You say you are doing parsing and REST call *not* in models and controllers?  Then, by definition, isn't it *not* a REST call?  Maybe some sample code of youro ruby, and the jquery/html you have right now (Try to make it the simplest version possible, as proof of concept)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I am making REST call to some other web service which is not written by me. For example I am making REST call to twitter REST API. In the dialog, user will enter a term ex: user to search. Based on search term, I am making REST call to search for a user in twitter. I will update my post with sample code.

Comment: This might be useful http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def users
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      render(:js => "callback(#{@users.to_json});")
    end
  end
end
```

Use something like this in your HTML to call that:

```
<%= link_to_remote "get users", :url => { :action => "users" } %>
```

More information on rendering vanilla JavaScript from a Rails action: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-vanilla-javascript

This example constructs JavaScript that calls a "callback()" function in your JavaScript code, with JSON data.  Your callback function will receive a JSON string that will be easy to parse.  You could also use to_xml to send XML if you really want, but parsing JSON is much simpler and faster.

You don't need a helper in this example because the JavaScript call that includes the data will come directly from your controller.  There is no view template, so you don't need a helper.  The best place for the code that gets the @users would be in a User model class.  Not an Active Record model, just a plain model.  The code that fetches the users from the remote REST API could possibly be a class method.  (If you're feeling lazy then you could set @users with the REST API response right there in the "users" controller action.  But that's not ideal use of Rails because the whole point of Rails is MVC.)

If you're using jQuery, then you could also use jQuery's getJSON() function so that your controller would send only the JSON data without using the callback: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Note that this is the simple kind of answer that you seem to be looking for, but this isn't really the best way to do this kind of thing for more complex applications.  The best way to do this kind of thing at the moment is with something like Backbone.js.  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/  With Backbone.js, you can define a "users" collection in JavaScript, set the REST URL of that collection (it can be a URL in your Rails app, which relays data from some other API) and then you simply call `users.fetch()` in your JavaScript to load the data.  It's very similar to Active Record, but for the client site.  It's better because it abstracts the process and allows you to update and delete records as well as simply listing them.

Comment: Thank you. I made use of Vanilla javascripts and getJSON in my project. It helped a lot